# Crosstab exists in one database, but not the other

Tags: postgresql

I have two databases on an instance. I can use the crosstab function in `Database1` without any problems. But when I try to use it from `Database2`, I get this error - `crosstab` function does not exist.

When I run, `Create extension crosstab`, I get this error - `could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-10/share/extension/crosstab.control": No such file or directory`

**UPDATE**

When I do a `\dx crosstab`, I get `List of installed extensions - 0 rows` in both the databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your first database, the `crosstab` extension was installed in the pre-9.0 fashion using an SQL script (and probably upgraded ever since).

Install the “contrib” modules on the second database (usually that is an installation package with `contrib` in the name), then create the extension.